# Is it reasonable to a open connection each time you send a command via serial port, TCP/IP and so on?

Tags: sockets, tcp, serial-port, tcpclient, visa

I'm developing software which controls various hardware via serial ports, [TCP/IP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_protocol_suite), USB, etc. The main program usually works for hours or even days without restart. Each action of the program processed as follows:

1. Open connection (port, VISA instr., TCP/IP)
2. Send message/receive answer
3. Close connection

The question is whether it's reasonable/safe/reliable to open and close connections each time? Or possibly it is better to open each connection just once per session at start?

Comment: That's how HTTP 0.9/1.0 worked for many years :). Each web page you opened in a browser, would trigger possibly 100s of HTTP requests, each opening a new socket connection, getting the data, and then closing it. It worked pretty well... Persistent connections improve latency and reduce the amount of work required, but unless you are dealing with a very high volume, you will probably not notice a difference.

Comment: Connection pooling is a solution to a performance problem, if you have a performance problem. Do you?